# Навигация по сайту без перезагрузки страницы

Tags: ajax

Всем привет. Делаю сайт-визитку. Захотел сделать загрузку новых страниц без перезагурзки текущей на аяксе. Читал в интернете как это можно реализовать, но что-то не выходит. Пробовал [этот](http://habrahabr.ru/post/154617/) вариант, он вообще не заработал. Прошу посоветовать простые библиотеки для этого.

Comment: а зачем для сайта-визитки аякс?.. вордпресс для этого есть..

Comment: что? а скажите ка, а какая разница на чём делаю я визитку, я про аякс спрашивал, или же подобное что я написал нельзя организовать на wordpress?!?!

Comment: Для сайта-визитки (впрочем, как и для многих других) важна возможность положить любую страницу в закладки. Если это будет - делайте хоть на аяксе, хоть на паровой тяге :-)

Comment: да пофиг, в принципе. не встречал я "простых библиотек" для создания одностраничных аякс-сайтов. то ли плохо искал, то ли их просто не делают ввиду примитивности задачи. Можно написать самостоятельно с помощью jquery, если интересно - напишу ответом идеологию, а позже - примерчик

Answer (score 2):

Юзай jQuery - http://jquery.com/
А что у тебя не получается? Вот простой пример jQuery.ajax запроса:

```
$.ajax({
   url: "/api/getWeather",
   data: {
      zipcode: 97201
   },
   success: function( dataFromServer ) {
      $( "#weather-temp" ).html( "<strong>" + data + "</strong> degrees" );
   }
});
```

data - это данные которые ты передаёшь на сервак;
succes - функция которая выполняется при получении ответа от сервера
dataFromServer - данные которые пришли с сервера.

Я себе представляю это так:
1) вешаешь на каждую ссылку функцию которая выполняется по клику
2) при нажатии на ссылку отпраляешь запрос на сервер с данными (где данные это к примеру имя страницы которую ты хочешь открыть)
3) сервер обрабатывает твой запрос и возвращает ответ
4) и отображаешь пришедшие данные